# Is focal length in pixel unit a linear measurment

Tags: camera, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have a pan-tilt-zoom camera (changing focal length over time). There is no idea about its base focal length (e.g. focal length in time point 0). However, It is possible to track the change in focal length between frame and another based on some known constraints and assumptions (Doing a SLAM).

If I assume a random focal length (in pixel unit), for example, 1000 pixel. Then, the new focal lengths are tracked frame by frame. Would I get correct results relatively? Would the results (focal lengths) in each frame be correct up to scale to the ground truth focal length?

For pan and tilt, assuming 0 at start would be valid. Although it is not correct, The estimated values of new tili-pan will be correct up to an offset. However, I suspect the estimated focal length will not be even correct up to scale or offset.. Is it correct or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick short answer - if pan-tilt-zoom camera is approximated as a thin lens, then this is the relation between distance (z) and focal length (f):

[image]

This is just an approximation. Not fully correct. For more precise calculations, see the [camera matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_matrix). Focal length is an intrinsic parameter in the camera matrix. Even if not known, it can be calculated using some camera calibration method such as DLT, [Zhang's Method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-9He7Nu3u8s) and [RANSAC](https://www.cc.gatech.edu/classes/AY2016/cs4476_fall/results/proj3/html/rkatoch3/index.html). Once you have the camera matrix, focal length is just a small part of it. You get many more useful things along with it.

OpenCV has an inbuilt implementation of Zhang's method. (Look at this [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html) for explanations, but code is old and unusable. New up-to-date code below.) You need to take some pictures of a chess board through your camera. Here is some helper code:

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
from scipy import linalg

x,y = np.meshgrid(range(6),range(8))

world_points=np.hstack((x.reshape(48,1),y.reshape(48,1),np.zeros((48,1)))).astype(np.float32)

_3d_points=[]
_2d_points=[]

img_paths=glob('./*.JPG') #get paths of all checkerboard images

for path in img_paths:
    im=cv2.imread(path)
    
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(im, (6,8))
    
    if ret: #add points only if checkerboard was correctly detected:
        _2d_points.append(corners) #append current 2D points
        _3d_points.append(world_points) #3D points are always the same


ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(_3d_points, _2d_points, (im.shape[1],im.shape[0]), None, None)

print ("Ret:\n",ret)
print ("Mtx:\n",mtx)
print ("Dist:\n",dist)
```

You might want Undistortion: Correcting for Radial Distortion

```
# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((6*8,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:6,0:8].T.reshape(-1,2)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

for fname in img_paths:
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (6,8),None)    
    
    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)

        cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners)

    if 'IMG_5456.JPG' in fname:
        plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
        img_vis=img.copy()
        cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img_vis, (6,8), corners, ret) 
        plt.imshow(img_vis)
        plt.show()
```

[image]

```
#Calibration
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)

# Reprojection Error
tot_error = 0
for i in range(len(objpoints)):
    imgpoints2, _ = cv2.projectPoints(objpoints[i], rvecs[i], tvecs[i], mtx, dist)
    error = cv2.norm(imgpoints[i],imgpoints2, cv2.NORM_L2)/len(imgpoints2)
    tot_error += error

print ("Mean Reprojection error: ", tot_error/len(objpoints))

# undistort
mapx,mapy = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(mtx,dist,None,newcameramtx,(w,h),5)
dst = cv2.remap(img,mapx,mapy,cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
# crop the image
x,y,w,h = roi
dst = dst[y:y+h, x:x+w]
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
#cv2.drawChessboardCorners(dst, (6,8), corners, ret) 
plt.imshow(dst)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
# Reprojection Error
tot_error = 0
for i in range(len(objpoints)):
    imgpoints2, _ = cv2.projectPoints(objpoints[i], rvecs[i], tvecs[i], mtx, dist)
    error = cv2.norm(imgpoints[i],imgpoints2, cv2.NORM_L2)/len(imgpoints2)
    tot_error += error

print ("Mean Reprojection error: ", tot_error/len(objpoints))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. However, I was not asking about how to find this initial focal length since it is not possible in my case. I was asking about how the random estimation of this focal length will affect the whole tracking journey. Thanks again for your efforts!

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Simple estimation won't work because of the complexities discussed. and its not a linear relation. Your intuition is correct that the estimated focal length will not be correct up to scale or offset. People use camera calibration via camera matrix for SLAM. This is a good blog https://www.kudan.io/archives/356

Comment: Thanks. got your idea now.